# Facing issue with IE 11 on windows 10, browser is launched but does not enter URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Selenium Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\Automation\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.get("http://google.co.in");
```

Error :

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.8.0.0
Listening on port 25160
Only local connections are allowed
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session null does not exist (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'TS-39', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
```

Comment: Any time the browser launches but the URL is not entered, the first thing you should do is make sure you that your Selenium driver and browser is up-to-date (or at least matching versions if you've intentionally downgraded).

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session null does not exist
```

### Reason

The main reason you are seeing **`SessionNotFoundException`** is because of the following reasons :

- You are using the **InternetExplorerDriver** of version **3.8.0.0** which is apparent from the logs below and is properly initiated.

  ```
  Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
  3.8.0.0
  Listening on port 25160
  Only local connections are allowed
  ```
- But your **`Selenium`** version is **2.53.1** which is apparent from the logs below :

  ```
  Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
  ```
- Moreover your **JDK** version is much older of version **1.8.0_91** which is apparent from the logs below :

  ```
  System info: host: 'TS-39', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
  ```

### Solution

The simple solution would be :

- Update your **JDK** version to current levels **JDK (Java SE 9.0.1)**.
- Update your **Selenium-Java Client** version to current levels **v3.8.1**.
- Update your **InternetExplorerDriver** version to current levels **v3.8.0.0**.
- Execute your `Test`.